# How to sign the CSR to enable a private Certificate Authority (CA) in AWS ACM? (How to generate version 3 cert?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, vpn, aws-acm

I'm trying to setup a private Certificate Authority (CA) in AWS ACM in order to setup a direct VPN connection to a VPC without internet access (on purpose).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html

So in the VPN Client configuration I need to get the Server certificate ARN.  That's where I've gone to try and setup the private CA in order to setup the `Client VPN Endpoint`.

Currently, I've created the *Private CA* in ACM, but need to:

> Import a CA certificate to activate your CA.

I'm a little unclear on what's going on here.  At the moment it's just me, so I've done the following:

(Following this link: https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309 )

On Local PC:

1. Create root CA Private Key:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096
   ```
2. Create and self-sign the "`Root Certificate`" on local pc:

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt
   ```

   3. Generate the certificate for AWS service, "`AWS Service Certificate`", with CA Root key(Private Key)/Root Certificate and the AWS issued CSR:

   ```
   openssl x509 -req -in AWS-PRIVATE-CSR.pem -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out service.aws.crt -days 500 -sha256
   ```

Then from the AWS ACM Console:

4. From the `Import CA Certificate` dialog:

   - Add "`AWS Service Certificate`" as the *Certificate body*
   - Add "`Root Certificate`" as the *Certificate chain*

At this point I get the error when I click, "Confirm and Import":

> CertificateMismatchException
>   The certificate version must be greater than or equal to 3.

I checked the version of the generated, "`AWS Service Certificate`" with t he the following command, and it shows as *Version 1*.

```
openssl x509 -in service.aws.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
    ...
```

So apparently I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't seem to find what it is.  To resolve the current AWS error my question is:

- How can I generate a `Version: 3` cert using the root Key/Cert and AWS CSR?

Alternatively what's the best way to connect to a VPC without internet access?  If it's easier to setup a VPC<->VPC connection where I can access the other VPC via SSH that could work.

Comment: You must either have a very old version of openssl or have some weird openssl config setup.  It should generate v3 certificates and has done for a very long time now...

Comment: Ok, I'll check. The interesting thing is that the generated `root certificate` is generated as version 3.  I noticed that one uses the `req` command resulting in version 3, while the CSR certificate command `x509` is used, resulting in version 1....

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

Comment: upgrading version with procedure here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102803/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-1-0-to-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was incorrect in my comment that it may be your openssl version.  The instructions are a little off on generating the certificate from the CSR.  The problem is that you don't have openssl setup correctly to do this.

The easiest fix is to create a text file (e.g. v3.ext) with the contents of:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
```

The add the following to your openssl command line "-extfile filename" e.g. "-extfile v3.ext"

So your openssl command will be:

> openssl x509 -req -in AWS-PRIVATE-CSR.pem -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey
>   rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out service.aws.crt -days 500 -sha256
>   -extfile v3.ext

You can then verify with

> openssl x509 -in service.aws.crt -text -noout

That should generate you a v3 certificate.

Comment: beautiful! Yes, I've confirm that this gives me a v3 Certificate!

Comment: At this this got me to the next error: `The basic constraints extension must specify that the certificate is for a CA.`

Comment: Updated the following line in the `v3.ext` file created that you mentioned the cert import successfully: `basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE`